# MediaRecorder.Prepare() IllegalStatEexception

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am trying Android voice recording app by [Official Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder) and it gives me crash at  `recorder.start();` because prepare statement not executed.

The only change i made in my app is location where i need to store audio recording where official documentation using

```
 // Record to the external cache directory for visibility
        fileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        fileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
```

My Code

```
String subfolder = "Exotel/Media/Audio/Voice Messages/Audio Temp";
                        String filename = "Exotel"+"_Voice"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".3gp";
                        String TempPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) + File.separator + subfolder;
                        File Dir = new File(TempPath);
                        if (!Dir.exists()){
                            Dir.mkdirs();
                        }
                        TempPath = TempPath+File.separator+filename;

                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: Temp Path "+TempPath);
                        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        recorder.setOutputFile(TempPath);
                        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                        try {
                            recorder.prepare();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed "+e.getMessage());
                        }

                        recorder.start();
```

If i use  `fileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(); fileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";`
then my code is working perfectly. Also if i change the extension to `.mp3` then it also working in this case. I don't understand what exactly wrong in my code. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

```
private var myAudioRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null
private var outputFile: String? = null
```

Call **setupAudioRecordSource** method in **onCreate** of your activity

```
private fun setupAudioRecordSource() {
        outputFile = createPathToSaveAudio()
        myAudioRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        myAudioRecorder?.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        myAudioRecorder?.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
        myAudioRecorder?.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
        myAudioRecorder?.setOutputFile(outputFile)
     
    }

private fun createPathToSaveAudio(): String? {
    val storageDir = getAttachmentFilePath()
    return File(
        storageDir,
        "recordedAudio_" + Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis.toString() + ".3gp"
    ).absolutePath
}

fun Context.getAttachmentFilePath(): String {
    val storageDir = File(
        this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),
        "Attachment"
    )
    if (storageDir?.exists() == false) {
        storageDir.mkdirs()
    }
    return storageDir.absolutePath
}
```

When I start recording audio call below method

```
   private fun recordAudio() {
        try {
            myAudioRecorder?.prepare()
            myAudioRecorder?.start()
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

After recording call below method in stop button

```
   private fun stopAudio() {
        if (myAudioRecorder != null) {
            try {
                myAudioRecorder?.stop()
                myAudioRecorder?.reset()
                myAudioRecorder = null
            } catch (e: java.lang.IllegalStateException) {
                //  it is called before start()
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
                // no valid audio/video data has been received
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1: You can add answer to your existing answer. No need to add one more answer.
2: You are using `getExternalFilesDir` which gives you app specific folder which is not not accessible for other app. So it doesn't answer my question.